# How to put $y=5$ and $x=(-3)$ into discussion form?

Tags: calculus

Discuss the slope, $y$-intercept and graphs of the following:

a) $y=5$
  b) $x=-3$

How can I answer this in discussion form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Discuss the slope" just means "talk about the slope". The reason the question is phrased that way is because, while a horizontal line has a slope, a vertical line does not. Hence, you can say something like "the slope of a vertical line is undefined", or something to that effect.

Answer (score 0):

There is a mnemonic device: **HOYVUX**
**H** orizontal lines have 
**0** (zero) slope and their equations are 
**Y** = (some constant)
**V** ertical lines have
**U** nderfined slope and their equations are in the form
**X** = (some constant)

Comment: Also, a vertical line $x = c$ has no y-intercept, and x-intercept (c, 0). Likewise, a horizontal line $y = c$ has no x-intercept and the y-intercept is (0, c)

Comment: Unless, of course, $c = 0$.

Comment: WLOG assume $c \neq 0,\pm  \infty$

Comment: You do lose generality by assuming $c \ne 0$, since $c = 0$ is a qualitatively different case.  You might argue that it's trivial, but then, so is $c \ne 0$ too.

Comment: I might argue that your sense of humor is qualitatively different than mine... Without loss of generality, of course.